# WPML WordPress How to make product (Lock Icon)

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have trouble with products multi languages when setting the stock quantity of different language right now when I want to change the quantity of the translated product, it's showing me the lock icon in quantity field is there is an easy way of changing the quantity for other languages? Thank you.

Comment: In WPML, you can't have different stock quantities across different languages. Your only option is to create a different product in each language and set the quantity for that product.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.